# Realtime notification to me from database

Tags: android, mysql, sql, notifications, localnotification

I have an android app which sends data submitted by users to my database hosted in a server. Every time data is stored in my SQL database.. I need to receive[realtime] the data on my pc or cellphone from the sql database every time a submits some data. How can I implement this ?

Comment: check out real time messaging services like, RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ and ZeroMQ

Comment: It's specifically needed to work with database since we need to tally certain things at the end of every month. So I need to make sure it stores the data to db and I get a realtime notification.

Comment: yes you can do that with above services

Comment: So I can retrieve the data from db and rabbit mq will notify me on my cellphone .. If that works .. It will be cool.

Comment: I have used RabbitMQ and it can do the job in real time and can be triggered to do a task, to send the data to your phone you probably want to use something like google cloud messaging

Comment: i will try to check some tutorials on how rabbitmq works. ty

Comment: yep that would be great, my friend works at the company who made RabbitMQ

Comment: since i need 2 more rep to chat on stack.. can you pass me your skype or IM id.. i wanted to ask in detail about rabbitmq .. ty